# node modules: module.exports and require() not working for a local module

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to require the "*add*" function from "*helper.js*" into "*app.js*".
The two files are in the same folder.

The issue is that I keep getting the error:
**ReferenceError: add is not defined**

Can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

The screenshot attached shows how things things look like.

Thank you.

[Screenshot of my VS code showing the files and the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tcJi.png)

Comment: Code in your question should be pasted directly into the question as text and NOT only available as a screenshot.  This is for a whole bunch of good reasons such as it can't be search indexed in an image, code can't be pasted into answers, it's not very accessible, etc...

Comment: I understand, however I wanted to show that the js files are in the same folder

Comment: none of that changes that the code should be shown as text in the question.  You CAN fix your question with the edit link.

Answer (score 1):

When you import another module, you don't import the *identifiers* declared in the other module - you only import whatever was assigned to the `module.exports`. Here, that's the `f`.

You need:

```
const add = require('./helper');
add(3, 5);
```

Or

```
const f = require('./helper');
f(3, 5);
```

The only way you'd be able to use the original `add` without taking it from the `require` statement would be if the other module assigned the function to the global object (which is really weird and should not be done in a module system, except in rare circumstances when assigning a module namespace to the window, like jQuery and other libraries do).